# Class javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá estou com esse error ao tentar modela uma class no javascript:

```
Player.makePlayer(player,1)
       ^

TypeError: Player.makePlayer is not a function
```

class player:

```
class Player {
    constructor() {
      this.id = null;
      this.socketId = null;
      this.name = null;
      this.mmr = null;
    }
    makePlayer(player,socketId){
      this.id = player.id
      this.socketId = socketId
      this.name = player.name
      this.mmr = player.mmr
    }
  }

  module.exports = Player;
```

tenho um mesmo problema em minha class match:

```
class Match {
    constructor() {
      this.id = null
      this.players = null
      this.isActive = null;
    }
    addPlayers(players,socketId){
      this.id = uuid.v4().toString();
      this.socketId = socketId;
      this.players = players;
      this.isActive = false
    }
  }
```

mas na minha class match eu precisaria de um array de match, e não estou conseguindo imaginar como solucionar isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que você está invocando o método de instância `makePlayer(player,socketId)` como se fosse um método de classe.

Eu vejo duas abordagens possíveis:

A primeira abordagem é manter a classe `Player` do jeito que está e criar uma instancia onde será feita a chamada do método de instância `makePlayer()`.

```js
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.id = null;
    this.socketId = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.mmr = null;
  }
  makePlayer(player, socketId) {
    this.id = player.id
    this.socketId = socketId
    this.name = player.name
    this.mmr = player.mmr
  }
}

//Instancia a classe Player
let jogador = new Player()

//envoca o método makePlayer na instancia jogador
jogador.makePlayer({
  id: 1,
  name: "Jhon McBrian",
  mmr: null
}, 2345)

//Exibe as informações da instancia jogador
console.log(jogador)
```

A segunda abordagem é modificar o `makePlayer()` transformando-o de um método de instância para um método de classe, adicionando a palavra chave [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) no início da declaração do método, e o tornado `makePlayer()` um [object factory](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1brica_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_objetos)) da classe `Player`.

```js
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.id = null;
    this.socketId = null;
    this.name = null;
    this.mmr = null;
  }
  
  //Class factory para classe Player
  static makePlayer(player, socketId) {
    let p = new Player();
    p.id = player.id
    p.socketId = socketId
    p.name = player.name
    p.mmr = player.mmr
    return p //O factory deve retornar o objeto construído no método
  }
}

//envoca o factory makePlayer na classe Player
let jogador = Player.makePlayer({
  id: 1,
  name: "Jhon McBrian",
  mmr: null
}, 2345)

//Exibe as informações da instancia jogador
console.log(jogador)
```

Para classe match é o mesmo problema e ambas as abordagens resolvem o problema, no caso eu mantive `Match.addPlayers()` como método de instância.

```js
class Match {
  constructor() {
    this.id = null
    this.players = null
    this.isActive = null;
  }
  addPlayers(players, socketId) {
    //Esse sandbox não possui objeto uuid
    this.id = '2c5ea4c0-4067-11e9-8bad-9b1deb4d3b7d' //uuid.v4().toString(); 
    this.socketId = socketId;
    this.players = players;
    this.isActive = false
  }
}

//Inicia um array com duas inst6ancias Match
let arr = [new Match(), new Match()];

//para elemento do array envoca o método addPlayers
arr[0].addPlayers({
  id: 1,
  name: "Jhon McBrian",
  mmr: null
}, 2345)

arr[1].addPlayers({
  id: 2,
  name: "Silio Santos",
  mmr: null
}, 3251)

console.log(arr)
```

Aqui usando object factory em um método estático(método de classe).

```js
class Match {
  constructor() {
    this.id = null
    this.players = null
    this.isActive = null;
  }

  static addPlayers(players, socketId) {
    let m = new Match()
    //Esse sandbox não possui objeto uuid
    m.id = '2c5ea4c0-4067-11e9-8bad-9b1deb4d3b7d' //uuid.v4().toString(); 
    m.socketId = socketId;
    m.players = players;
    m.isActive = false
    return m
  }
}

//Inicia um array 
let arr = [];


arr[0] = Match.addPlayers({
  id: 1,
  name: "Jhon McBrian",
  mmr: null
}, 2345)

arr[1] = Match.addPlayers({
  id: 2,
  name: "Silio Santos",
  mmr: null
}, 3251)

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Olá você poderia me ajudar sobre o match?

Comment: obrigado mano!!

Comment: match? Não entendi?

Comment: No final da pergunta eu postei minha class match eu estou com dúvida de como fazer um array ed minha class Match

Comment: Agora que eu vi, vc quer um array

Comment: simm eu provavelmente vou ter que ter uma class de suporte não?

Comment: Feita a edição.

Comment: obrigado mano, você acha desnecessário criar uma class suporte match manager para fazer isso ou é desnecessário?

Comment: Depende do que você quer fazer. Tudo que for implementar no código deve de preferência facilitar e possuir utilidade. Se um class manager for util para o desenvolvimento então o implemente, mas caso não possua finalidade alguma sua implementação é um desperdício de tempo.